# Send multipart(File) with some parameters using retrofit

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to send file (Image) and some parameters to server, then my php script will send them to database. I have already tried. My file has been uploaded in server and the name of file has been uploaded in database but the parameters is not included.

I will show my code. I hope you can help me.

ApiService.java

```
public interface ApiService {

    /*
    Retrofit get annotation with our URL
    And our method that will return us the List of Contacts
    */
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload(Testing).php")
    Call<Result> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                             @Part("id_user") RequestBody idUser,
                             @Part("p_id_doc_proj") RequestBody p_id_doc_proj,
                             @Part("id_doc_type") RequestBody id_doc_type,
                             @Part("id_project") RequestBody idProject);

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Permission List
     */
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    /**
     * Context Variables
     */
    Context mContext;

    /**
     * Views
     */
    View parentView;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    /**
     * Image path to send
     */
    String imagePath;
    String idUser = "4";
    String p_id_doc_proj = "90";
    String id_project = "16";
    String id_doc_type = "1";

    /**
     *
     */
    PermissionsChecker checker;

    /**
     *
     */
    Toolbar toolbar;

    /**
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        /**
         * Parent View
         */
        parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentView);

        /**
         * Permission Checker Initialized
         */
        checker = new PermissionsChecker(this);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        assert fab != null;
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imagePath)) {

                    /**
                     * Uploading AsyncTask
                     */
                    if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(mContext)) {
                        /******************Retrofit***************/
                        uploadImage();
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_internet_connection_warning, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_message_to_attach_file, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Upload Image Client Code
     */
    private void uploadImage() {

        /**
         * Progressbar to Display if you need
         */
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.string_title_upload_progressbar_));
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        //Create Upload Server Client
        final ApiService service = RetroClient.getApiService();

        //File creating from selected URL
        File url = new File(imagePath);

        // create RequestBody instance from file
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), url);
        RequestBody userID = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, idUser);
        RequestBody idDocProj = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, p_id_doc_proj);
        RequestBody idProj = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, id_project);
        RequestBody idDocType = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, id_doc_type);

        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", url.getName(), requestFile);

        final Call<Result> resultCall = service.uploadImage(body, userID, idDocProj, idDocType, idProj);

        // finally, execute the request
        resultCall.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //Snackbar.make(parentView, response.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Snackbar.make(parentView, response.body().getResult().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Response Success or Fail
                /*if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body().getResult().equals("success")) {
                        imagePath = "";
                        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //Snackbar.make(parentView, response.body().getResult().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    //else
                        //Snackbar.make(parentView, response.body().getResult().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    //Snackbar.make(parentView, response.body().getResult().toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }*/

                /**
                 * Update Views
                 */
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_upload_fail, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing Image Picker
     */
    public void showImagePopup(View view) {
        if (checker.lacksPermissions(PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE)) {
            startPermissionsActivity(PERMISSIONS_READ_STORAGE);
        } else {
            // File System.
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

            // Chooser of file system options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, getString(R.string.string_choose_image));
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1010);
        }
    }

    /***
     * OnResult of Image Picked
     *
     * @param requestCode
     * @param resultCode
     * @param data
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1010) {
            if (data == null) {
                Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_unable_to_pick_image, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                return;
            }
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File(imagePath))
                        .into(imageView);

                Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_reselect, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cursor.close();

                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_unable_to_load_image, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void startPermissionsActivity(String[] permission) {
        PermissionsActivity.startActivityForResult(this, 0, permission);
    }
}
```

RetroClient.java

```
public class RetroClient {

    /**
     * Upload URL of your folder with php file name...
     * You will find this file in php_upload folder in this project
     * You can copy that folder and paste in your htdocs folder...
     */
    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://172.xx.x.xxx/Upload/";


    public RetroClient() {

    }

    /**
     * Get Retro Client
     *
     * @return JSON Object
     */
    private static Retrofit getRetroClient() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static ApiService getApiService() {
        return getRetroClient().create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is my server side code

```
<?php
    $file_path = "";
    $id_project = $_REQUEST["id_project"];
    $p_id_doc_proj = $_REQUEST["p_id_doc_proj"];
    $id_doc_type = $_REQUEST["id_doc_type"];
    $id_user = $_REQUEST["id_user"];

    $url1 = "http://172.x.x.x/Upload_Ruben/";
    $url2 = $file_path.basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $url = $url1.$url2;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $url2)){
        $ws = "http://172.x.x.x:xxxx/UploadImage/$id_project/$p_id_doc_proj/$id_doc_type/$id_user/$url";

        $opts = array('http'=>array('header'=>'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);

        $arrayLog = array();
        $data1 = file_get_contents($ws, false, $context);
        $result = json_encode($data1);
    }else{
        $result = array("result" => "error");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you send it

```
@Multipart
@POST("/edit_user_profile")
Call<String> editProfileServerCall(@Part("access_token") RequestBody 
accessToken, @Part("user_name") RequestBody name, @Part("user_mobile") 
RequestBody userPhone, @Part("user_email") RequestBody email, @Part 
MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Here is how you call it -

```
public void editProfileServerCall(final Context context, String name, String phoneNumber, File image, String email, final ProfilePresenter.EditProfilePresenter editProfilePresenter) {

    editProfilePresenter.showLoader();
    RequestBody userName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name);
    RequestBody userPhone = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), phoneNumber);
    RequestBody userEmail = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), email);
    RequestBody accessToken = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), Constants.userData.getAccessToken());
    RequestBody file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), image);
    MultipartBody.Part userImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("user_image", image.getName(), file);
    RestClient.getApiService().editProfileServerCall(accessToken, userName, userPhone, userEmail, userImage).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            editProfilePresenter.hideLoader();
            Log.e("edit_profile_response",""+ response.body().toString());
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                if (object.getInt("is_error") == 0) {
                    if (object.has("user_profile")) {
                        CommonParser.parseProfileData(context, object.getJSONObject("user_profile"));
                        editProfilePresenter.success();
                    }
                } else {
                    editProfilePresenter.error(Constants.popupResponseObject.getJSONObject("" + object.getInt("flag")).getString("text"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                editProfilePresenter.error(Constants.serverError);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            editProfilePresenter.hideLoader();
            editProfilePresenter.error(Constants.serverError);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but the response always onFailure

Comment: Yes, i think i don't get all parameters, only image url. I have updated my question. Could you help me? I'm new at create php server side script.